# Nested while loop not working with mysql database queries

Tags: php, mysql

What I want to achieve is create a table with order id & related product information. If one order id contains more than one product, order id should be printed only once in first row while for further rows only product information should be present starting from second column.
I tried nearly couple of hours working on this but couldn't find a solution. Below is the code:

```
$query3= "select orderid from orders_main where userid=$cus_id";
    $results3= mysql_query($query3);
    while ($row = @ mysql_fetch_array($results3))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th width:17%>".$row["orderid"]."</th>";
        $temporderid=$row["orderid"];
        $query2 = "SELECT product_name, quantity, subtotal from orders where orderid='$temporderid'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    while ($row2 = @ mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {
            echo "<th width:35%>".$row2["product_name"]."</th>";
            echo "<th width:13%>".$row2["subtotal"]."</th>";
            echo "<th width:22%></th>";
        echo "</tr>";
                            echo "<th></th>";
        }
    }
        echo "</table>";
    }
```

What happens is it only prints the order id & not any product information. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that there is data in those columns?

Comment: Of course buddy there are lots of data.

Comment: Well, you probably don't want to overwrite your `$row` variable for one. Second, ask the second query if it had an error. Third, don't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated. Take a look at PDO.

Comment: paste the var_dump here

Comment: @user3024288 - in addition to Justin's points... What is the `@` symbol being used for in `@ mysql_fetch_array`?

Comment: Sorry pasted old code, didn't use row twice. Second, query at least fetching results in sqlYog, plus value of $temporderid is coming fine as well. Don't know about mysql_* functions whether those causing this.

Comment: @user3024288 - the issue with mysql_* functions is that they're being deprecated, and will be removed from PHP completely in the future. If that was the problem right now, you'd see a different set of error messages.

Comment: @ symbol is used for fetching rows, without it, it will just give null exception. It's the way I've always fetched my data.

Comment: Don't use nested queries. Especially when the inner query is based on data from the outer one. Use a single `JOIN`ed query.

Comment: @user3024288 - that's not what it's for; `@` is normally used to suppress error message from functions. If your code is generating errors, you should be outputting them so you can fix them, not hiding them.

Comment: @andrewsi: Thanks buddy, I never knew that, literally. :(

Comment: Code is updates: issue I'm having is as soon as it goes to second row for a single orderid, it starts printing from the first column i.e. OrderID which I want to be blank for rows other than first for a particular orderid, any suggestions what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo:

```
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
           ^---no S

while ($row2 = @ mysql_fetch_array($results2))
                                          ^--- S
```

If you weren't using tha @#%@#%@#$$#@@#$%@#$@# `@` error suppression operator, you'd have gotten the "attempting to fetch from ..." error.

Never **EVER** use that moronic operator. **ESPECIALLY** when you're having trouble getting the code to work. YOu've done the equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your hears and chanting "lalalalala can't hear you.... "

Comment: I hate typos. By the way, thanks a ton, it worked. :)

Comment: One more issue: as soon as it goes to second row for one order id, it starts printing from the first column i.e. OrderID which I want to be blank for rows other than one. Can you help?

Comment: your `</tr>` is inside the inner loop. move it to the end of the main loop

Comment: Thanks @MarcB for your suggestion, however adding one column after </tr> worked fine. Adding <tr> at the end of inner loop will never have additional rows I guess.

Comment: yeah, but look at the html you'll be generating. `<table><tr><th><th><th></tr><th><th><th>etc...` it'll be a totally invalid table.